# pyqt5 no centra la ventana

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Buenas tardes etoy tratando de centrar mi app con el siguiente codigo:

```
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QDialog, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, Qt, QtGui
import sys


class Principal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("12.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.frame.resize(2000,1000)
        self.frame_2.resize(self.frame.width()-1900,self.frame.height())
        self.center()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

    def center(self):
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        print(centerPoint)
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
p.resize(1000,600)
app.exec_()
```

pero no centra la app.. alguna idea¿?

Comment: te funciono mi solucion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es simple, tu estas redimensionando la ventana despues de centrarla, esa causa que el punto bottomRight se mueva y no se vea ese efecto, la solucion es centrar despues de hacer todos los cambios:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Principal(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("12.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.frame.resize(2000,1000)
        self.frame_2.resize(self.frame.width()-1900,self.frame.height())
        self.resize(1000,600)
        self.center()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

    def center(self):
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        print(centerPoint)
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```